# Failed to remove ThreadLocal when the web application was stopped with log4j2.0-rc1 configuration

Tags: asynchronous, log4j2

I implemented logging module using log4j2 for my web application. It's running on tomcat server. I was using log4j2-beta9 version earlier and deployed my application in test regions. Recently I migrated to log4j2.0-rc1 version of logging modules and enabled asynchronous logging.
But when I shutdown my application, I am observing following errors in catalina.out. As per log4j2.0-rc1 release notes, similar issues were fixed under this latest release, but I am observing the similar errors

SEVERE: The web application [/Example1] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@1701b802]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.Info] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger$Info@71d7971a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/NullConfiguration
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.stop(LoggerContext.java:210)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContext.stop(AsyncLoggerContext.java:57)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext$ShutdownThread.run(LoggerContext.java:437)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
```

I am not sure what could be the reason for this issue. Appreciate if anyone can explain the root cause for this issue. Is it issue with log4j2 library or with my application configuration.
FYI, I am using RollingRandomAccessFile appender with system property 
-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an existing issue in log4j2: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-493

One of the workarounds (mentioned in ticket LOG4J2-493) is to remove the log4j2 jars from the web server (container) shared lib folder and instead include the log4j2 jars in WEB-INF/lib of your web application.

Comment: Thanks Remko for your quick reply. When I revisit my application jar file configuration, I found that my application was referring log4j2-beta9 version, hence the issue persist for my application. Now I corrected the code and it's referring log4j2-rc1, but I am seeing below error for one or two instances but it reduced when compare to earlier. Let me monitor for two days and confirm whether the issue resolved or not. FYI, my application is configured to include all jars in WEB-INF/lib of my web application.

Comment: OK. Please make sure there is no log4j2 jar remaining in the webserver shared lib folder. If the issue persists, please raise a ticket on the log4j2 issue tracker.

Comment: Hi Remko, still I am observing few instances of below errors in catalina.out when I am shutdown and restart the application SEVERE: The web application [/Example1] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@1701b802]) and a value of type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.Info] (value [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLogger.....Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak. But it's not hindering to write log file. So not sure does it require any action to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had memory leaks with log4j2 but that was due to wrong configuration. I had log4j2 jars in the tomcat/lib folder, the Log4jContextSelector was set in the web.xml and the path to config file was also set in the web.xml. And the WebAppClassLoader was still hanging in the memory even after undeploying the application. And the Thread stack pointed directly to log4j2. So the solution for me was to put all the configuration and the jars in the tomcat. [Here I have written more of the explanation of my issue](http://programtalk.com/java/log4j2-contributing-to-memory-leakage/)